# Why does setAttribute 'false' work on another button but not on self in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, accessibility

I have a menu that uses buttons and vanilla Javascript.
When a button is clicked, it adds the class `opened` to the button and changes `aria-expanded="false"` to `aria-expanded="true"`.

If you click another button, the original button's attribute reverts to `aria-expanded="false"` and the class `opened` is removed.

However, if you click the original button a second, consecutive time, whilst the class `opened` is removed, `aria-expanded="true"` does not change back to `aria-expanded="false"` and I am really struggling to understand why.

Here is the script and a mini-menu with minimum CSS (obviously, the browser's inspector is required to view the changes).
NB The original JS below was written for a multi-level menu, obviously not used in this instance.

```js
for (const selector of [".btn-level-1", ".btn-level-2", ".btn-level-3", ".btn-level-4", ".btn-level-5", ".btn-level-6",]) {
    const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    for (const button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        buttons.filter(b => b !== button).forEach(b => {
            b.classList.remove('opened'); // this works on self and also if other button is clicked
            b.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false"); //this doesn't work on self
        });
        button.classList.toggle('opened');
        button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
    })
}}
```

```css
button + ul {
  display: none;
}
button.opened + ul {
  display: block;
}
li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidenav {
  width: 560px;
  background: #eee;
}
.visually-hidden { 
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px; 
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu-toggle {
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.icon {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="Main Navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="https://example.com/some-category">Some Category</a>
            <button class="btn-level-1 menu-toggle" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="christmas-red"></span>
            <span class="icon">+</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">
            <span class="toggleText">show submenu</span> for "Some Category"</span>
            </button>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://example.com/some-category/item-1">Some Category Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://example.com/some-category/item-2">Some Category Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="https://example.com/some-category">Another Category</a>
            <button class="btn-level-1 menu-toggle"  type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="christmas-red"></span>
            <span class="icon">+</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">
            <span class="toggleText">show submenu</span> for "Some Category"</span>
            </button>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://example.com/another-category/item-1">Some Category Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://example.com/another-category/item-2">Some Category Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: you filter out the clicked button from the list of buttons before the loop that sets `false`, so `opened` gets toggled, but `aria-expanded` is always set to `true` for the button that is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After toggling the `opened` class on `button` you need to check whether you actually added or removed it when setting the `aria-expanded` attribute. You can do this using `classList.contains`. Updated working example:

```js
for (const selector of [".btn-level-1", ".btn-level-2", ".btn-level-3", ".btn-level-4", ".btn-level-5", ".btn-level-6",]) {
    const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    for (const button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        buttons.filter(b => b !== button).forEach(b => {
            b.classList.remove('opened');
            b.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
        });
        button.classList.toggle('opened');
        // check which aria-expanded value we should set below
        let ariaExpanded = button.classList.contains('opened').toString();
        button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", ariaExpanded);
    })
}}
```

```css
button+ul{
  display: none;
}
button.opened+ul{
  display: block;
}
li{
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidenav {
  width: 560px;
  background: #eee;
}
.visually-hidden { 
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px; 
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu-toggle{
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.icon {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="Main Navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="https://example.com/some-category">Some Category</a>
            <button class="btn-level-1 menu-toggle" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="christmas-red"></span>
            <span class="icon">+</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">
            <span class="toggleText">show submenu</span> for "Some Category"</span>
            </button>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://example.com/some-category/item-1">Some Category Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://example.com/some-category/item-2">Some Category Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="https://example.com/some-category">Another Category</a>
            <button class="btn-level-1 menu-toggle"  type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="christmas-red"></span>
            <span class="icon">+</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">
            <span class="toggleText">show submenu</span> for "Some Category"</span>
            </button>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://example.com/another-category/item-1">Some Category Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://example.com/another-category/item-2">Some Category Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Many thanks. That's a great help. Now need to change the `innerHTML` of one of the spans.